# I want to store an array in a variable using php

Tags: php

```
  $curl_response = '[OPT: value]';
  $obj = json_decode($curl_response);
  print_r( $obj->OPT); `
```

This is what iI am trying to do but I got error while trying to save OPT value

```
stdClass Object ( [MSISDN] => 03142985338 [OPT] => 161 [ResponceCode] => 0020 [ResponceMessage] => Success )
Notice: Trying to get property 'OPT' of non-object
```

Comment: Your JSON value is not correct

Comment: Additionally code seems to be missing. If you would execute your code snippet, you should get a warning, as $obj should be null.

Answer (score 2):

You define $curl_response as '[OPT: value]' which is not valid JSON. A correct JSON object literal of its content would be

```
$curl_response = '{"OPT": "value"}';
```

I think in your code json_decode($curl_response) results in $obj == null for that reason, which does not contain OPT as a property.

To get to $obj->OPT that actually contains 'value' you can go like this:

```
$curl_response = '[OPT: value]';

// some string manipulation
$curl_response_elements = explode(': ', trim($curl_response, '[]'); // split string to array at ': '
$object_key = trim($curl_response_elements[0]);                     // remove spaces
$object_value = trim($curl_response_elements[1]); 

$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->$object_key = $object_value;

print_r($obj->OPT);
```

Reading your question again, you want to store an array in a variable, not an object. Your print_r suggested you were looking for an object. To get your data into an array, define it as array instead of stdClass:

```
$obj = array();
$obj[$object_key] = $object_value;
```

Or shorthand:

```
$obj = [$object_key => $object_value];
```

Keep in mind you need to modify your print_r if you use an array instead of an object:

```
print_r($obj['OPT']); // returns 'value' from array
```